# ActionLayout for navigationview items displays on right side

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I'm developing an application where I'm using new design support library's navigation view controller for drawer menu. Everything is working fine. I've set items for navigation view using `app:menu` attribute. Item's are perfectly displayed. Now i'm adding `app:actionLayout` for those item's and it's also getting added but the problem is it's getting displayed at right side in the view.

**My Activity XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <afour.com.uniapp.customwidgets.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:FontName="@string/type_face_splash" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />

        </RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header_layout"
    app:paddingStart="0dp"
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My menu file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_about"
    android:title="@string/aboutus"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/logout_item_layout"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

**my action layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/aboutus"
    android:padding="05dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" />

<afour.com.uniapp.customwidgets.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="@string/logout"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:FontName="@string/type_face_regular" />

</LinearLayout>
```

PFA of the issue [image: See the action layout displayed in red in right corner]

Answer (score 3):

In your code I see you don't have a title in the item with the actionLayout, but now Android requires it. I set it to @null and it fixed the design:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
    title:"@null"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/logout_item_layout"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView" />
```

Comment: wow this is insane. I set it as an empty string for it's required and now @null suddenly solved this.

Comment: @amrut, this answer should be marked as the correct answer. following this i solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

In your action layout xml file, you can fix your problem adding to the root view (a LinearLayout in your case) the following properties:

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   android:layout_gravity="start">
```

But take note what the documentation says about actionLayout:

> android:actionLayout: 
>   Layout resource. A layout to use as the action view.
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

And an actionView:

> An action view is an action that provides rich functionality within
>   the app bar. For example, a search action view allows the user to type
>   their search text in the app bar, without having to change activities
>   or fragments.
>   https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html

So maybe that's isn't the best way to display a custom view in your MenuItem.

Seeing your code, why not just add the icon and text to the item element?

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
    android:text="@string/logout" />
```

But if you really need it, the right way to display the custom view is implementing a ListView with ViewHolder pattern.